# Scala class with SortedMap and "reversed" SortedMap

Tags: scala

I'm a Scala novice. I'm looking to create a class in Scala with two mutable `SortedMap`s, one in normal sorted order (increasing) and one in reverse sorted order (decreasing)

```
class MyClass {
  var mapNormal : SortedMap[Int, Int] = SortedMap.empty
  var mapReversed : ??? = SortedMap.empty
}

var x  = new MyClass
x.mapNormal += (1 -> 50)
x.mapReversed += (2 -> 51)
```

How can I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [API docs for `SortedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMap$), you will find that `SortedMap.empty[A]` takes an implicit `Ordering[A]`. That means, you can call the method like you did, and have the implicit automagically resolved (to the default ordering for `Int`, which is just what you would think it is) or you can provide an explicit ordering:

```
class MyClass {
  var mapNormal : SortedMap[Int, Int] = SortedMap.empty
  var mapReversed : SortedMap[Int, Int] = SortedMap.empty(mapNormal.ordering.reverse)
}
```

The implicit ordering for `Int` is defined in the companion object of [`scala.math.Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.math.Ordering$@Int) along with the other default orderings, just in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately scala doesn't have mutable sorted map (TreeMap for example), so you can use only immutable version.

If you need reverse order in second map you need to provider reverse ordering parameter

```
  // Key ordering
  implicit val Ord = implicitly[Ordering[Int]]

  val map = SortedMap.empty[Int, Int]
  val reversedMap = SortedMap.empty[Int, Int](Ord.reverse)

  println(map + (1 -> 50, 2 -> 51))
  println(reversedMap + (1 -> 50, 2 -> 51))
```

Output:

```
Map(1 -> 50, 2 -> 51)
Map(2 -> 51, 1 -> 50)
```

Comment: How about scala.collection.SortedMap? I thought it is mutable unlike scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap.

Comment: If you'll check the code you'll se that it's calling immutable version: 'def empty[A, B]: SortedMap[A, B] = immutable.SortedMap.empty[A, B])'